Dynamically Union Pyspark Dataframes
My files in the lake are split by 2 partitions, partition_Continent and partition_Country.
I have a df_grouped that tells me which filter to use, for example let's say this gives me 2 records:

I've created a filter_condition based on the df_grouped above:
filter_condition = " OR ".join(
    [
        (
            f"(partition_Continent = '{i.Continent}'"
            f" AND partition_Country = '{i.Country}')"
        )
        for i in df_grouped.distinct().collect()
    ]
)


So when I run
df_presented = spark.read.parquet(f'abfss://laketommy@tommy.dfs.core.windows.net/Tommy').where(filter_condition)

it will give me all the records in those 2 partitions.
But I believe it is quicker to read directly from the partition as opposed to using a where clause, i.e. something like
df_presented = spark.read.parquet(f'abfss://laketommy@tommy.dfs.core.windows.net/Tommy/partition_Continent=Europe/partition_Country=UK').union(spark.read.parquet(f'abfss://laketommy@tommy.dfs.core.windows.net/Tommy/partition_Continent=Asia/partition_Country=China'))

How can I achieve this based on what gets returned in df_grouped?

A simple for-loop should work here:
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

df_presented = spark.createDataFrame([], StructType([]))
for row in df_grouped.distinct().collect():
    file_path = f'abfss://laketommy@tommy.dfs.core.windows.net/Tommy/partition_Continent={row.Continent}/partition_Country={row.Country}'
    try:
        df_presented = df_presented.unionByName(spark.read.parquet(file_path), allowMissingColumns=True)
    except:
        print("some error")


I ended up finding a slightly different solution where I use append and reduce like below
`    dfs_presented = []
for l in partition_paths:
try:
dfs_presented.append(spark.read.parquet(f'abfss://laketommy@tommy.dfs.core.windows.net/Tommy/'{l}'))
except:
print(f'Path does not exist: abfss://laketommy@tommy.dfs.core.windows.net/Tommy/{l}')
df_presented = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs_presented)

`
any performance difference between the two?
